# Estimation problem in econometric model

Tags: time-series, estimation, stata

I am trying to estimate the following equation:
$$Y_{i,t+1}=(λβ)X_{i,t}^{'}+(1-λ)Y_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t+1}$$
but I don't understand how to find the $\lambda$ estimate especially since $X'$ consists of multiple variables. In this equation, $\lambda$ is a scalar and $\beta$ is a vector. Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of model type? I am using Stata 12 for this problem and my data is an unbalanced panel. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the equation so that it looks nicer.  Could you describe a bit more about your problem.  Is $\beta$ a vector or a scalar?  what is the dimension of the $X_t^'$ matrix?  Does this model contain an error term?

Comment: The model does have an error term and X' contains 7 independent variables.

Comment: This looks a lot like a first-order exponential smoothing model, which corresponds, in Box-Jenkins speak, to an ARIMAX(0,1,1) model.  ($Y_{t+1}-Y_t = e_{t+1} - \lambda e_t$, where $e_t = Y_t - \beta X_t$).  I'm not familiar with Stata, so I can't help you past the suggestion that you look for some regression estimation with ARIMA errors routines.

Comment: Thanks. I found how to do an ARIMAX(0,1,1) but Stata doesn't like the multiple panels.

Comment: $\lambda$ is one minus the coeff on $Y_{i,t}$? But this is a dynamic panel that violates the strict exogeneity assumption. You should use Stata's `xtabond` command.

Comment: I need to use system GMM (Blundell and Bond) for the final estimation but I also need to do the same regression using OLS with year fixed effects and another regression with both year and firm fixed effects. I think xtabond2 with do the system GMM but the OLS version is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I did not understand how to get Stata to do combinations of coefficients. The code that appears to work is:

```
reg F.MDR MDR EBIT_TA MB DEP_TA lnTA L.FA_TA RD_DUM RD_TA Ind_Median
nlcom  (Lambda: 1 - _b[MDR])(EBIT_TA: _b[EBIT_TA] / (1 - _b[MDR])) ///
(MB: _b[MB] / (1 - _b[MDR])) (DEP_TA: _b[DEP_TA] / (1 - _b[MDR])) ///
(lnTA: _b[lnTA] / (1 - _b[MDR])) (FA_TA: _b[L.FA_TA] / (1 - _b[MDR])) ///
(RD_DUM: _b[RD_DUM] / (1 - _b[MDR])) (RD_TA: _b[RD_TA] / (1 - _b[MDR])) ///
(Ind_Median: _b[Ind_Median] / (1 - _b[MDR])) (Constant: _b[_cons])
```

where `MDR` is the `Y` in the question's equation and $X'$ consists of `EBIT_TA MB DEP_TA lnTA L.FA_TA RD_DUM RD_TA Ind_Median`. As @richardh says, $\lambda$ is (1- $\beta$ of MDR) and `nlcom` can be used to recover the actual $\beta$'s on the independent variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your own solution looks reasonable, although I would probably call it tedious. Another reasonable approach would have been to use the nonlinear regression or GMM:

```
    generate lagged_x = L.x
    generate lagged_y = L.y
    nl (y = ( {lambda}*( {b0} + {b1}*lagged_x ) + (1-{labmda})*lagged_y ) )

    gmm ( y - {lambda}*( {b0} + {b1}*L.x ) - (1-{labmda})*L.y ), instruments( L.x L2.x L.y L2.y)
```

or something of that kind. (Updated to write up the lagged values explicitly for `nl` which does not support lags.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, I need to compare another type of GMM model to this model so I can't use GMM for this step. The nl command looked promising but doesn't seem to work. The error message generated is "factor variables and time-series operators not allowed"

Comment: I don't see how another model being a GMM model conflicts with this. Can't you do `hausman` or something like that for two `gmm` models?

Comment: I'm replicating a paper and that paper uses system GMM by Blundell and Bond as the base case estimation and compares it to 2 OLS models: 1 with year fixed effects and the other with both firm and year fixed effects. As far as I know, the gmm command only implements difference GMM rather than system GMM in the xtabond2 command.

Comment: `xtabond2` and `gmm` are entirely different commands. I am not a time series person, so I can't really tell, but my understanding is that you can do nearly ANYTHING with `gmm`, while `xtabond2` is a specific application where all the matrices are spelled out explicitly to optimize speed and space, that's all.